# Hide all ValidationMessageFor on a button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view I have two buttons, the first one will validate & fire all the ValidationMessageFor errors on click.The validations are defined in the Model.

Code for validation : `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BookTitle)`. Like that I have validation for many controls.

On the second button click if the validation message is already shown because of the first button click, I want to hide it all. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect them in Chrome of Firebug you'll notice that validation messages come with `field-validation-error` class. So hiding them should be super easy:

```
$(".field-validation-error").hide()
```

Comment: It helped me to fix an issue which i have been working throughout the day. Thanks indeed!!!